# iptables and blocking potentially impossible traffic

Tags: linux, security, firewall, iptables

I am working on some iptables firewall rules and have seen many examples that suggest the importance of blocking potentially impossible traffic from non-routable IP address spaces.  This would include items from RFC 1918, RFC 1700, RFC 5735, RFC 3927, RFC 3068, RFC 2544, RFC 5737, RFC 3171, and RFC 919.  Some examples include the following:

- $CURRENT_IP
- 0.0.0.0/8
- 10.0.0.0/8
- 127.0.0.0/8
- 169.254.0.0/16
- 172.16.0.0/12
- 192.0.0.0/24
- 192.0.2.0/24
- 192.88.99.0/24
- 192.168.0.0/16
- 198.18.0.0/15
- 198.51.100.0/24
- 203.0.113.0/24
- 224.0.0.0/4
- 240.0.0.0/4
- 255.255.255.255

Some of the examples indicate that you only need to worry about checking for this traffic if it is the source of the traffic.  Example of:

```
$IPT -A ANTISPOOF -s 0.0.0.0/8 -m limit --limit 5/min --limit-burst 5 -j LOG --log-prefix "Denied Spoofed Source IP Address: "
$IPT -A ANTISPOOF -s 0.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
```

In other examples, a more aggressive stance is taken where they check for the source and destination for both input and output.  Examples include:

```
iptables -A INPUT -d 172.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -s 172.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 172.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 172.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
```

I remain with the following questions:

- Do I need to check for the source address of the IP ranges listed above in the bulleted list?
- Do I need to check for the destination address of the IP ranges listed above in the bulleted list?
- Is is important to create rules for the IP ranges listed above that would include both the INPUT and OUTPUT chains?
- Are there any IP ranges that I have forgotten to check from that are missing from the bulleted list above?

Thanks in advance for your help with this.

Comment: The OUTPUT chain is packets originating from your machine itself so you do not have to put them there. And why would you limit traffic if you are not going to accept it just drop it

Comment: @topdog: The `limit` rule is only there to log the bad packets (Personally, I'd only log for as long as it took to see that the rule was working and then turn it off. Most Bogon traffic is just noise)

Comment: 192.88.99.1 is NOT a bogon, it is the 6to4 relay anycast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the above ruleset deals with what is typically called Bogon Filtering: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogon_filtering  - These are packets that are to/from unallocated areas of the address space.

3 of those ranges, however, are RFC1918 private networks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_networks - Packets from these can still class as Bogons, but only if they're not legitimate. (Even a rose is a weed, if it's growing in the middle of a car park...)

If this is a router you're working with, Consider the following:

- The INPUT and OUTPUT chains deal with traffic destined to / from (respectively) some local process on the firewall itself. Most routed traffic won't touch these chains.
- The FORWARD chain deals with traffic routed through the machine for some other destination.
- Typically, you'll want to block *inbound* traffic from those *source* networks and *outbound* traffic to those *destination* networks. Have a look at the `-i` flag to iptables, which lets you limit a match to a given network adaptor.

  - I second topdog, though, in that trapping outbound traffic like this is probably not necessary. If it's your server, you should be in control of what it's sending.
- Remember that your internal LAN probably uses one of the private address ranges. You probably still want to allow that traffic through.

Answer (score 1):

```
* Do I need to check for the source address of the IP ranges listed above in the bulleted list?
```

Yes, you do not want your server trying to answer/sending packets to the listed addresses even though your isp/nsp should discard them.

```
* Do I need to check for the destination address of the IP ranges listed above in the bulleted list?
```

Yes, incoming packets would not get passed up to operating system but you want to block the attempts as close to the edge of you system/network.

```
* Is is important to create rules for the IP ranges listed above that would include both the INPUT and OUTPUT chains?
```

Yes, you do not want to be sending packets to the listed addresses.

```
* Are there any IP ranges that I have forgotten to check from that are missing from the bulleted list above?
```

Yes, Your IP address should be denied incoming to you. You can get more aggressive by using ( http://www.team-cymru.org/Services/Bogons/ ) but you could be blocking legitimate sources as the remaining ipv4 address are allocated.

The iptables hit count will help you determine which rules are working and logging will help with identifying the connections whether denied or accepted.